# How to set default parameters for a graphical device?

Tags: r

I like to read white on black. So, in R I would do something along the lines of:

```
par (bg = "black")
par (fg = "ivory1")
```

I would like these options to be set by default. However, one does not simply write these lines in `.Rprofile` because, as I understand, at the time it gets executed, the graphical device is not yet initialized. Rather, as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13480570/2108477), one should re-assign `options()$device` to include the necessary option setting. I did not have success in that.

This is what I tried:

*`~/.Rprofile`*

```
f_device <- options()$device

blackdevice <- function (...) {

    f_device(...)

    par (bg       = "black")
    par (fg       = "ivory1")
}

options (device = blackdevice)
```

The idea here is to save the original `device` function to another variable, and then call it from my new `device` function. What I get is:

```
Error in f_device(...) : could not find function "f_device"
```

— At the time I run `plot (something)`.

Another idea I had is to go like that:

*`~/.Rprofile`*

```
.First <- function () {

    options(f_device = options()$device)

    blackdevice <- function (...) {

        options()$f_device(...)

        par (bg       = "black")
        par (fg       = "ivory1")
    }

    options (device = blackdevice)
}
```

— Assigning the original `device` someplace else in `options`. But this leads to:

```
Error in (function (...)  : attempt to apply non-function
```

I'm out of ideas. Can you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that the `device` option is not yet set at the time `.Rprofile` is processed.
Therefore, `options()$device` is `NULL` at that point, which leads to the error you are observing.

The `.First()` function also gets executed before the packages from `options("defaultPackages")` are attached, so that gives the same error.

If you want to put something in `.Rprofile`, it would have to be like:

```
setHook(
    packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
    function(...) {
        f_device <- getOption("device")

        blackdevice <- function(...) {
            f_device(...)
            par(bg = "black")
            par(fg = "ivory1")
        }

        options(device = blackdevice)
    }
)
```

Note that **this is a solution for the standard R GUI**, but not for e.g. RStudio, which sets its own `"RStudioGD"` device *afterwards* (and requires that `grDevices` is already loaded).

(This also explains the awkward approach (from the question you linked) of re-defining `"RStudioGD"` in `.Rprofile` to get it ahead of `"tools:rstudio"` on the search path)

Answer (score 13):

One solution seems to be to define a 'hook' that is called when a new plot is created. From the documentation of `plot.new`:

> There are two hooks called ‘"before.plot.new"’ and ‘"plot.new"’  (see
>   ‘setHook’) called immediately before and after advancing the  frame.
>   The latter is used in the testing code to annotate the new  page. The
>   hook function(s) are called with no argument.  (If the  value is a
>   character string, ‘get’ is called on it from within the  ‘graphics’
>   namespace.)

The following seems to work:

```
setHook("before.plot.new", function(...) {
  par(bg = "black",
    fg = "ivory1",
    col.axis = "ivory1",
    col.lab = "ivory1",
    col.main = "ivory1",
    col.sub = "ivory1")
})
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you choose to call `par` 6 times instead of one time with all arguments?

Comment: @r2evans No, not really, I copied the first two from the question; added the others later to get the axes and labels right. Fixed it now. Thanks